# Has any part of St. Alphonsus' Moral Theology translation into English had a valid Imprimatur?

Tags: catholicism, reference-request, translation, alphonsus-liguori, imprimatur

Regarding [*Mediatrix Press*'s English Translation project](https://mediatrixpress.com/current-projects/st-alphonsus-liguori-theologia-moralis/) of the 10 Latin volumes of [St. Alphonsus's *Moral Theology*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphonsus_Liguori#Moral_theology) where these 2 volumes (Book 1 to Book 4 part 1) have been published:

- [Volume 1 Book 1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0692864571)
- [Volume 1 Book 2-3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06XYM6Y4J)
- [Volume 2 Book 4a](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1953746217)

Though one cannot tell from the *Mediatrix Press*'s or Amazon websites, I suspect this edition has no Imprimatur. I don't think *Mediatrix Press* submits their translations for such review, at least based on their books that I am familiar with, such this volume from the [Bellarmine Translation Project](https://mediatrixpress.com/current-projects/bellarmine-translation-project/), [*De Controversiis* Tomus I - *On the Roman Pontiff*](https://www.amazon.ca/dp/0692453644).

Also, this publication from [*Liguori Publications*](https://www.liguori.org/amfile/file/download/file_id/630/product_id/10227/) seems to be very abbreviated and comes with no Imprimatur from the local ordinary.

Finally, I'm not sure that this treatise on truthfulness by the Saint is directly a part of his *Moral Theology*: [*On Truthfulness*](https://ia800202.us.archive.org/11/items/a626327600liguuoft/a626327600liguuoft.pdf)

QUESTION: Is any part of the *Moral Theology* of St. Alphonsus de Liguori available in English *with* a valid Imprimatur; i.e., from the local ordinary of where the book is published, or from the local ordinary of the translator? If so, where may I obtain it?